# How to enable CORS in Spring Boot and Angular

Tags: angular, spring, spring-boot, api, cors

I have enabled CORS in my spring boot server as follows.

```
@RestController
@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:4200")
@RequestMapping("/api/v1")
public class EmployeeController {
    @Autowired
    private EmployeeRepository employeeRepository;

    @PostMapping("/employees")
    public Employee createEmployee(@Valid @RequestBody Employee employee) {
        return employeeRepository.save(employee);
    }
}
```

When creating a new employee I get the error as,

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:8080/springboot-crud-rest/api/v1/employees' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

I also tried to enabling Server-Side Proxy on Angular CLI Apps Which Have Been ejected but I could not find any file as **webpack.config.js**.

Comment: updated answer below. please check.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In CORS changes no changes are required on frontend side. Backend have to configure it properly, If you have this backend deployed over cloud then some settings are required. Else you should be fine with approach you have done

Just put same CrossOrigin over @PostMapping like below as well. And it should be fine.

```
@RestController
@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:4200")
@RequestMapping("/api/v1")
public class EmployeeController {
    @Autowired
    private EmployeeRepository employeeRepository;

    @CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:4200")
    @PostMapping("/employees")
    public Employee createEmployee(@Valid @RequestBody Employee employee) {
        return employeeRepository.save(employee);
    }
}
```

By the way its not best practice to use this annotation on each api. instead configure this in your application.properties so that its applicable for all APIs.

Comment: How do you put inside application.properties to enable it globally ? I've tried multiple configurations but none seem to work